# Operador de entrada Clase

Tags: c++, clase, operador

Estoy haciendo una clase con dos numeros como variables, no me da error de compilacion, pero cuando en el archivo main intento leer un objeto por teclado usando el operador de entrada me salta el error, he buscado errores de sintaxis pero no encuentro nada, tambien he comparado con otras clases similares:

```
D:\C++\Clases\main.cpp|10|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'usuario()')|
```

Os dejo aqui los tres archivos, se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Archivo clase:

```
#ifndef USUARIO_H
#define USUARIO_H
#include <iostream>

class usuario
{
    public:
        usuario();
        usuario(int numero, int exponente);
        usuario(const usuario& u);
        usuario& operator=(const usuario& u);
        usuario& operator*=(const usuario& u);
        int num() const;
         int exp() const ;




    private:
        int numero;
         int exponente;

};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, usuario& u);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const usuario& u);



#endif // USUARIO_H
```

Archivo Implementacion:

```
#include "usuario.h"

usuario::usuario():numero(1),exponente(1)
{

}
usuario::usuario(int numero, int exponente):numero(numero),exponente(exponente)
{

}
usuario::usuario(const usuario& u):numero(u.numero),exponente(u.exponente)
{

}
usuario& usuario::operator*=(const usuario& u)
{
    numero*=u.numero;
    exponente+=u.exponente;
    return *this;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in ,usuario& u)
{
    char ch;
    int numero;
    int exponente;
    in>>numero;
    in>>ch;
    in>>ch;
    in>>exponente;
    u = usuario(numero,exponente);
    return in;

}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const usuario& u)
{
    out<<u.num();
    out<<"x";
    out<<"^";
    out<<u.exp();
    return out;
}
int usuario::num()const
{
    return numero;
}
 int usuario::exp()const
{
    return exponente;
}

usuario& usuario::operator=(const usuario& u)
{
    numero = u.numero;
    exponente = u.exponente;
    return *this;
}
```

Archivo main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "usuario.h"



int main()
{
    usuario u1();
    usuario u2(1,1);
    std::cin>>u1;
    u1*=u2;
    std::cout<<u1;
    return 0;
}
```

Se que puede ser un fallo bastante basico, estoy empezando y aun no lo domino todo bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**Actualizacion:

Cuando el objeto u1 lo creo con el constructor por defecto, con parentesis vacios, no funciona, pero cuando lo creo sin parentesis o con otro valor si que funciona, no entiendo muy bien el motivo.